# xmldiff, how to suppress whitespace differences

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to use xmldiff in unit tests to compare xmls.
I have 2 xmls that, I'm quite happy are identical (and notepad++ agrees with me).

if I do

```
from xmldiff import main, formatting

diff = main.diff_trees(actual.getroot(),expected.getroot())
```

though I get a list of whitespace differences, that I want to ignore...e.g.

```
[UpdateTextIn(node='/schedule[1]', text='\n  '),
 UpdateTextIn(node='/schedule/contentGroups[1]', text='\n    '),
 UpdateTextAfter(node='/schedule/contentGroups[1]', text='\n  '),
 UpdateTextIn(node='/schedule/transmissions[1]', text='\n    '),
 UpdateTextAfter(node='/schedule/transmissions[1]', text='\n'),
 etc
```

How do I suppress these differences?

Answer (score 0):

ok, I suspect people will throw their hands in horror, I'm not a python programmer, but this seems to work

```
diff = main.diff_trees(expected.getroot(),actual.getroot())
meaningfulDiffs = \
    list(
        filter(
            lambda line: (line.text != None) and (line.text != ""),
            diff
            )
        )
self.assertFalse(any(meaningfulDiffs),msg = "errors=" + pprint.pformat(meaningfulDiffs))
```